# Why does my web page hang when I post back?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback, form-submit

I'm working on an asp.net web page which displays data from a SQL database.

There is a form that the user can fill out to update the data.  However, the form is not written with any ASP.net controls.  The form is submitted using jQuery `$('#myform').submit()`.

I have absolutely no problem with this page on my develpoment web server (VS development server, CASINI).  However, when I push this out to my production server farm, my users have intermittent problems with the post back not working.

The page always loads in response to a GET request, but when a user submits the form, it may or may not work.

One of four things will happen when the user submits the form.

1) The form submits and everything works - the data is updated.

2) The form submits and the server times out - the data is *not* updated.

3) The form submits and the server returns a blank page - the data is *not* updated.

4) The form submits and the user sees the message "Internet Exploder cannot display the page" - the data is *not* updated.

There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to when the page does or does not work.  The only consistent thing is that the page always loads for a GET request.

My session is *out of process* (for the server farm).

In no event is any meaningful error message returned.  Where should I start looking for the problem?

Comment: Can you post your code? Without it there is no chance of figuring out the issue.

Comment: Sounds like server problem, I would start by checking the Event Log.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could be getting a network timeout or code in an endless loop. Either unit test the DAL or start removing pieces until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a number of different layers here (Jquery, ASP.NET and I assume IIS for the server farm). I would use some logging to detect in which specific area your problem is.

If the whole thing is happening on your development machine you could either use Fiddler or Firebug to debug the problem with your HTTP requests.

Comment: To emphasize, there is absolutely no problem with this page on the development server.